# Outputting Library as ES6 module with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to bundle a library right now and Webpack doesn't seem to have an option for outputting as an ES6 module with `output.libraryTarget`. I see literally every option but ES6 listed in the documentation.

What's going on here? Am I misunderstanding how webpack works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented yet. See [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933).

You can use Rollup instead, but it expects all modules to be ESM.

Comment: Rollup can work with CJS using the commonjs and node-resolve plugins

Answer (score 1):

With the latest Webpack V5 (as of September 2022), you can do this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/index.ts"],


  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },

  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist/myOutputFile.mjs`,
    library: {
      type: "module",
    },
  },
};
```

I also set devtool: false and used externals to keep things like React out of the bundle.

See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933 (as mentioned in the other response) and https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytype for more details.